# Does the Alchemist feat apply to the UA Artificer healing draught?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, alchemist, potions, artificer

The Artificer gets a healing draught that he can hold out for an hour before it loses its healing properties. He technically gets an infinite amount of them, but a person can only drink 1/ long rest. Would the alchemist feat that allows you to maximize the healing of a potion also apply to this? my guess would be it is up to interpretation but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Alchemist feat does not apply the Artificer's healing draught.

The Alchemist feats says:

> Over the course of any short rest, you can temporarily improve the potency of one *potion of healing*...

It only works with the specifically named *potion of healing* magic item, which the Artificer's healing draught is not.